# NTAG424 Authentication Issue in IOS

Tags: swift, apdu, core-nfc, iso-7816-4

I'm having issues with authenticating an NTAG424 tag in iOS. I tried using the command 9071000002000000 as the NXP documentation suggests [AuthenicationCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgMqZ.png) & [AuthenticationCommandScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ3Xu.png), but I keep getting a **(Sw1 - 145 and Sw2 - 126 ) 917E** length error message. Can you help me fix this? I've included my iOS Swift code for you to check.

I tried to change expectedResponseLength is 0 so it'll gave
**Invalid expectedResponseLength value; should be from 1 to 65536 or -1.**
Then I change it to -1 so it will gave same **(Sw1 - 145 and Sw2 - 126 ) 917E.**
Can you please help me in that -

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        guard let firstTag = tags.first else { return }
        
        session.connect(to: firstTag) { (error) in
            if case let .iso7816(tag) = firstTag {
                let instructionClass: UInt8 = 0x90
                let instructionCode: UInt8 = 0x71
                let p1Parameter: UInt8 = 0x00
                let p2Parameter: UInt8 = 0x00
                let data: Data = Data([0x02, 0x00, 0x00])
                let expectedResponseLength = 1

                 let command = NFCISO7816APDU(instructionClass: instructionClass, instructionCode: instructionCode, p1Parameter: p1Parameter, p2Parameter: p2Parameter, data: data, expectedResponseLength: expectedResponseLength)

                tag.sendCommand(apdu: command) { (response, sw1, sw2, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("Error sending command: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }

                    print("Response: \(response)")
                    print("SW1: \(sw1), SW2: \(sw2)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```